# Inserting HTML in deep div in a table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div something like this:

```
<td class ="xyz">
    <div id = "1" class="1xyz">
        <div id="2" data-abc="abc" class="2xyz">
            <div id="3" tabindex="-1" class "3xyz">
                <input type="CheckBox" id="4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I would like to add "disabled" for the input type="CheckBox"

Comment: OK, so what problems are you having doing that? Going by your example this should be a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand what you mean, but if you only want to disable the element,
you can use the `disabled` attribute

```
<td class ="xyz">
    <div id = "1" class="1xyz">
        <div id="2" data-abc="abc" class="2xyz">
            <div id="3" tabindex="-1" class "3xyz">
                <input type="CheckBox" id="4" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

with vanilla javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("4").disabled = false; //enable
document.getElementById("4").disabled = true; //disable
</script>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$("#4").prop("disabled", true); //enable
$("#4").prop("disabled", false); //disable
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
```

If that's not the answer you want, you need to be clearer in your question.